# Use std::atomic in lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, atomic

I want to capture a `std::atomic` in a lambda expression. The lifetime of the atomic variable must be tied to the lambda, so I cannot capture by reference, but I want to avoid heap allocation.

**How can I modify the following snippet to make it compile and behave as intended?**

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic_int a{42};
    auto check = [a] () mutable { return a.fetch_sub(1) == 1; };
    //            ^ error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::atomic_int'
}
```

Comment: Why the life must be tied to lambda? The point of atomic types is that you share them between threads (main thread and some async thing where you will invoke the lambda - in your case). It means that you plan to keep your async operation running longer than the main thread, which doesn't seem like a good design.

Comment: @pptaszni The snippet just illustrates what I am trying to do and the error I get. My intention is to store the lambda in some shared state that is accessed by multiple threads. The shared state is generic and accepts any callable so I cannot store the atomic directly in the shared state (it would solve my problem though).

Comment: I guess that Callable cannot accept any arguments (like `std::atomic_int&`)? Then you might keep your atomic variable as a field (possibly static) of a class that is shared between the threads. It is hard to give the precise answer without knowing what exactly are you trying to do. As for the snippet in your question - the answer is simple: you cannot copy atomic types, you must pass it as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the capture directly and rely on C++17 guaranteed copy/move elision:

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    auto check = [a = std::atomic_int(42)]() mutable {
        return a.fetch_sub(1) == 1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this though? This just moves the problem one level up, now the lambda itself has to somehow be shared between threads, presumably with the same restrictions. It is now noncopyable and nonmovable.

Comment: did you just criticized your own answer?

Comment: @pptaszni I proposed a solution to the problem as stated, then criticized the entire premise. Stuffing an atomic directly into a callable to avoid lifetime issues and dynamic allocation will make it very hard to use. One can make a callable class to avoid the lambda capture problem entirely, but it will exhibit the same properties.